# Creating a list from the output of a for loop using itertools.product in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

My aim is to create a list for a deck of cards in python.  I am using itertools.product. The following code creates the correct list, however, it only works within the for loop.

**How can I store and use the list outside of the for loop?**

Printing the list **inside** the loop:

```
#CARDS#
import itertools
rank = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
suit = ["h", "d", "s", "c"]

for card in itertools.product(rank, suit):
    card_deck = card[0] + card[1]
    print card_deck
```

Output:

> 2h 2d 2s 2c 3h 3d 3s 3c 4h 4d 4s 4c 5h 5d 5s 5c 6h 6d 6s 6c 7h 7d 7s
>   7c 8h 8d 8s 8c 9h 9d 9s 9c Th Td Ts Tc Jh Jd Js Jc Qh Qd Qs Qc Kh Kd
>   Ks Kc Ah Ad As Ac

Printing the list **outside** of the loop:

```
for card in itertools.product(rank, suit):
    card_deck = card[0] + card[1]
print card_deck
```

Output:

> Ac

Comment: Same way you create a list of results in any loop. Remember the last time you built a list using a loop? Do you remember what you did then?

Comment: recommended reading: http://learnpythonthehardway.org

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you're done with the loop, `card_deck` still has the last value.  If you want all the values, then you need to store them somewhere ... maybe a list:

```
card_deck = []
for card in itertools.product(rank, suit):
    card_deck.append(card[0] + card[1])

print card_deck
```

And this looks like a real good candidate for a list comprehension:

```
card_deck = [card[0] + card[1] for card in itertools.product(rank, suit)]
```